# Report Automation

Tags: reporting

I want to add 2 more reports and also need to send that report to different users(1 report for some users, another report for some other users). please help me to create

```
global class Exporter implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O58000003m3Sa?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('report.xls');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'mplampla.com' } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

    }
 }
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: My above coding is running, but I need to add 2 more reports name and have to send that to different users.

Comment: cant you create 2 atachments for 2 other report and add it to the email?

Answer (score 0):

`sendEmail` method accepts the list of mails. All you have to do is create multiple emails and then add it to the email.

```
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
                ApexPages.PageReference report1 = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O58000003m3Sa?csv=1');
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attachment1.setFileName('report1.xls');
                attachment1.setBody(report.getContent());
                attachment1.setContentType('text/csv');

                ApexPages.PageReference report2 = new ApexPages.PageReference('/report2?csv=1');
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment2 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attachment2.setFileName('report2.xls');
                attachment2.setBody(report.getContent());
                attachment2.setContentType('text/csv');



                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message1.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment1 } );
                message1.setSubject('Report');
                message1.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
                message1.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'mplampla.com' } );

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message2 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message2.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment2 } );
                message2.setSubject('Report');
                message2.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
                message2.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'user2@ggg.com' } );


                Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message1 , message2 } );

            }
```

Comment: Hi Pranay, Thanks for the coding but I want to send report 1 to xyz user and report 2 to abc user

Comment: @Abinaya updated code